# Objective-C completion block in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I would like to call a completion block in Swift as I have always done in Objective-C. I took a look at closures, but for some reason, I cannot get it to work...

Obj-C:

```
- (void)someMethodWithParam1:(NSString *)param completion:(void(^)(NSArray* arr, NSURLResponse *resp))callback
{
    callback(arr, resp);
}
```

Swift:

```
func someMethodWithParam1(param: NSString, completion:((NSArray?, NSURLResponse?)->())) ->(){
                                                                                ^
                                                                                |
                                                                  /* Error: Insert ',' here */

    completion(arr, resp)

}
```

### EDIT

Okay, it was not a syntactical error, but an error from my side. The method header I used here is different from the one in my code. So this code that I originally posted should work fine.

Comment: "does not work" is not informative. Of course it does not work because if it did, you wouldn't have (hopefully) come to Stack Overflow. What **exactly, precisely** is the problem?

Comment: What error are you seeing?  What does the Swift closure look like?

Comment: @user3477950 I thought one could deduct from the Objective-C code what I am trying to achieve. I want exactly the same method in Swift as in the given Obj-C method. I have updated the question to show the error I get...

Comment: @the_critic "I thought one could deduct from the Objective-C code what I am trying to achieve" - we can deduct what you are trying to achieve, but we can't guess what error you get.

Comment: @user3477950 I was sure it was a syntactical kind of problem, and I thought it would be obvious to someone already familiar with closures. There aren't many resources on closures out there, which could have led me onto the right path, so sorry about that. I hope it is clearer now...

Answer (score 3):

Typealias's are your friend here, just to make the code more readable

```
typealias onComplete = (NSArray?, NSURLResponse?) -> ()

func someMethodWithParam1(param: NSString, completion:onComplete) -> ()
{

    completion(arr, resp)

}
```

Comment: I recommend using a `typealias` like a type, using capital letters when naming to avoid confusion. E.g. `typealias CompletionHandler = (NSArray?, NSURLResponse?) -> ()`

This way, you can tell your `typealias`'s from your variables.